# The sample size of sum of random variables

Tags: distributions, discrete-data

I was reading a paper and there was some confusing statements about the sum of two discretized independent random variables. So if X can get m values and Y can get n values then Z = X + Y could get m*n values? it shouldn't be m+n values?

Is it related to non-overlapping discrete values?or something else?

Could you please explain to me in which cases this can be happen?

**update:**

[image: Convolution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think in this way: for each value of $X$, $Y$ can assume $n$ different values, hence, for a fixed $X$, you can have $n$ different values. Since there are $m$ values for $X$, if there is no overlap, you get a total of $mn$ possible outcomes.

As an example, suppose $X$ takes values in $\{0, 1\}$ and $Y$ takes values in $\{0.1, 0.2, 0.3\}$. Their sum can take $6$ different values, namely $\{0.1,0.2,0.3,1.1,1.2,1.3\}$. If there is an overlap, this number can drop, e.g. if $X$ and $Y$ both takes values in $\{0,1\}$, their sum takes values in $\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: The PDF of the sums is convolution right? And convolution at non-overlapping values is 0. So the final distribution will have m+n-1 non-zero values. Are 0s considered in sample space?

Comment: If the random variables are independent then the PDF of the sum if the convolution. What I mean for overlap is in values of $X$ and $Y$ creating the same value for $Z$, for instance, the events {X=1,Y=0} and {X=0,Y=1} both implie {Z=1}. I think maybe you are understanding overlap differently. Using the first example in the answer, suppose $P(X=0) = 3/4$, $P(X=1) = 1/4$ and $P(Y=y)=1/3$ for $y \in \{0.1, 0.2, 0.3\}$. Then $P(X=0,Y=y) = (3/4)*(1/3)$, and $P(X=1,Y=y) = (1/4)*(1/3)$, hence all $6$ outcomes have positive probability. In this case, there is no overlap when computing the convolution.

Comment: @ I've added a graphical description of my problem. as you can see the convolution has non-zero values just at 7 points. However it is possible to have 15 values if the samples are not overlapping. Could you please explain to me graphically. I'm so confused. Thank you